# Insert dynamic number of child records

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, parent-child

Having a bit of a brain freeze right now, I have a variable that will capture a number. I need to use that number to insert that many child records. How can I accomplish that in SQL?

Ideally, i need an insert statement but I need it to execute as many times as my variable specifies.

If variable says 3...i need the insert to run 3 times...

Comment: To little to go on,share some sample data.

Comment: what's your table structure, what do you mean by 'child records', what is the 'parent record' what does the number mean?

Comment: Do you mean an `insert ... select` with a connect-by clause; or a PL/SQL loop? Or something else? Some context would be nice...

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't made it any clearer. Are you doing the insert in PL/SQL, from a client application, or something else? Where does the data for the columns come from, is it the same for all three inserts, and is it related to the parent? What kind of variable do you have - PL/SQL, substitution, a client (Java/C/PHP etc.)? You aren't giving us anything to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to go on in your question, and not clear if the data to be inserted is the same in each row, or different, but to insert 5 of the same rows:

```
INSERT INTO the_table ( c1, c2, c3 )
SELECT value1, value2, value3
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 5;
```

Or, in PLSQL:

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN 1..5 LOOP
     INSERT INTO the_table ( c1, c2, c3 )
     VALUES ( value1, value2, value3 );
  END LOOP:
END:
```